# Could I use variable in this.classList.remove

Tags: javascript, html

I  try to use this code in my javascript program:

```
this.classList.remove(RF.DangerClass);
```

Where RF.DangerClass is global variable.
But I get error -

> InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character

What's wrong? I can't use variable in this statement?

RF.DangerClass contain this string: **uk-form-danger uk-animation-shake**

What should I do if need to remove two classes?

Comment: Yes, you can use a variable there. What does `RF.DangerClass` contain?

Comment: I think I get the source of error - this variable contains "uk-form-danger uk-animation-shake". So the space is wrong character?

Comment: Yes, that is the cause of the InvalidCharacterError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the given class name may contain invalid characters (such as spaces), then first check if the class name is present before calling `remove`. The `remove` function may fail if the specified class name has invalid characters.

```
var classNames = ['invalid class', 'other-class']

classNames.forEach(function(name) {
    if (this.classList.contains(name)) {
        this.classList.remove(name)
    }
})
```

If the class names are known to be valid, you can remove multiple items with:

```
this.classList.remove('class1', 'class2')
```

Comment: what if I need to remove two or more classes?

Comment: Then you need to loop